# check input value for specific format using Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, input, validation

I have an input field that allows a user to enter a date.

I need this date to be in the following format: **10Jan13** (capitalization is not important)

There is a popup calender that if used will format the date correctly for the user.

I'd like to check the value of the input `onblur` using Javascript to be sure that the user did not either paste or type the date improperly.

I am currently checking number-only fields like this:

```
var numbers = /^[0-9]+$/;

if (!BIDInput.value.match(numbers))
{
    checkedInput.value = "";
    alert('Not a number');
}
```

and I'm checking letters-only fields like this:

```
var letters = /^[a-z]+$/ 

if (!nameInput.value.match(letters))
{
 nameInput.value = "";
     alert('Not a letter');
}
```

I would like to check the date format in a similar a fashion if possible. But anything that accomplishes the task will do. Can anyone point me in the right direction on how to get this done?

I know that client side validation does not replace server side validation. This is for user experience purposes only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're pretty much there with what you have. Basically your format is one or two digits, then one of 12 possible strings, followed by two digits. So for instance:

```
var shortDateRex = /^\d{1,2}(?:Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec)\d{2}$/;
```

Breakdown:

- `^` Start of string.
- `\d{1,2}` One or two digits.
- `(:?...)` A non-capturing group. Or you could use a capture group if you like.
- `Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec` An *alternation*, allowing any of those twelve choices. Naturally you can add more if you like. If you have two choices that start the same way (`Jan` and `January`, for instance), put the longer one earlier in the alternation.
- `\d{2}` Two digits.

---

Side note: I'd have to recommend against two-digit dates on principle, and particularly given where in the century we currently are!

---

Responding to Amberlamps' comment that this doesn't validate the *date*: Once you've validated the format, it's trivial to then check the date itself if you like (to rule out `30Feb13`, for instance):

```
var validateDateString = (function() {
  var monthNames = "Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec".toLowerCase().split("|");
  var dateValidateRex = /^(\d{1,2})(Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec)(\d{2})$/i;
  var arbitraryCenturyCutoff = 30;

  function validateDateString(str) {
    var match;
    var day, month, year;
    var dt;

    match = dateValidateRex.exec(str);
    if (!match) {
      return false;
    }
    day   = parseInt(match[1]);
    month = monthNames.indexOf(match[2].toLowerCase()); // You may need a shim on very old browsers for Array#indexOf
    year  = parseInt(match[3], 10);
    year += year > arbitraryCenturyCutoff ? 1900 : 2000;

    dt = new Date(year, month, day);

    if (dt.getDate() !== day ||
      dt.getMonth() !== month ||
      dt.getFullYear() !== year) {
      // The input was invalid; we know because the date object
      // had to adjust something
      return false;
    }
    return true;
  }

  return validateDateString;
})();
```

...or something along those lines.

[Live Example](http://jsbin.com/anibuj/1) | [Source](http://jsbin.com/anibuj/1/edit)

Or if (like me) you hate to see a list like that list of month names repeated you can use the `RegExp` constructor with a string instead, but you have to remember to duplicate your backslashes:

```
var monthNamesString = "Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec";
var monthNames = monthNamesString.toLowerCase().split("|");
var dateValidateRex = new RegExp("^(\\d{1,2})(" + monthNamesString + ")(\\d{2})$", "i");
```

[Live Example](http://jsbin.com/anibuj/2) | [Source](http://jsbin.com/anibuj/2/edit)

Comment: This will not validate a valid date though.

Comment: @Amberlamps: The OP said *"I would like to check the date **format**..."* (my emphasis).

Comment: @Amberlamps: It is not the job of regex, though. Calendar logic should be validated separately.

Comment: I am not arguing with you. I was just leaving that comment for any future visitor to know that this expression will not validate a date.

Comment: If you already validated the string format using `match`, you could put the different parts in brackets and use the return value for date validation.

Comment: @Amberlamps: Quite true, could certainly do that. **Edit**: Oh, and *I really want to*, what with having allowed one-digit days!!

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Wow man. You really went above and beyond here. Thank you very much. The best part is that I understand exactly how this works now and it taught me quite a lot. Thanks again!

Comment: T.J. Crowder I am trying to use this technique to limit the responses for a currency field. I want to allow 1, 2, 3, or 4 digits before a decimal and then only 2 digits after.  I thought this would work: `var priceForm = /^\d{1,2,3,4}.\d{2}$/`; but it does not. Any ideas?

Comment: @Killuh-B: You really should post your own question. But the answer is to start with `^\d{1,4}` which means "1 to 4 digits at the beginning" (the numbers in `{}` are a range, not a list).

Comment: @T.J. Crowder I thought about posting the question as a new one, but I was afraid of getting negative points for posting a redundant question, and it seemed as though maybe it was such a short question that it didn't deserve its own question.  Apologies for the faux pas, but thanks for the syntax answer

Answer (score 2):

You would use the following regular expression to check for a string starting with 2 numbers, followed by 3 characters followed by 2 numbers

```
[0-9]{2}[a-zA-Z]{3}[0-9]{2}
```